# Darken img while exposing text on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

Some images in my website needs to be darken when hovered, and also in the same time, to expose text that was hidden before that hover(the text will be displayed on top of the darken image).

I already implemented the img-darken part this way - http://jsfiddle.net/4Dfpm/.

What is a good way to implement the "expose text on hover(the same hover)" part?
Can it be done only with CSS, or I'll need to use a script this time ?

Thanks.

** How the img-darken part already implemented:

```
​

a.darken {
    background: black;
}

a.darken img {
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

a.darken:hover img {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Comment: Don't do this!  Don't obscure the exact thing that people are trying to focus on!  By all means, dim *everything else* on the page, but not the very thing that you most want to emphasise...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**CSS Solution**

Worked on your jsfiddle and changed jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/4Dfpm/55/

I have added < span > inside < a > tag with class=darken

```
<span>text</span>
```

And updated css is

```
a.darken{
...;
position:relative;
...
}
```

new css added is

```
a.darken span{position:absolute;top:5px;color:#000;left:10px}
a.darken:hover span{color:#fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
            transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obvious jQuery solution:  Add the message in the markup:

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="darken">
    <img src="http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/example.jpg" width="200">
    <span class="message">Some message here</span>
</a>
```

Add some css:

```
a.darken span{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px; left:0px;
    float:left;
    color:white
}
```

Sprinkle of JQuery:

```
$('.darken').hover(
    function(){
       $(this).find('.message').fadeIn(1000);
    },
    function(){
       $(this).find('.message').fadeOut(1000);
    }
    );
```

Et Voila: http://jsfiddle.net/4Dfpm/56/

Comment: Obviously not a jQuery solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a script to do that

HTML:

```
<div class="hoverText">Some text</div>
```

Js:

```
$("img").hover(
  function () {
    $(".hoverText").show();
  }, 
  function () {
    $(".hoverText").hide();
  }
);​
```

Css:

```
 div.hoverText{display = none;}
```

This a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/HFgGx/

Adjust this mockup with your logic ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://cssdesk.com/hrKeE

```
.captioned {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
  .captioned img {
    display:block;
  }
  .captioned .caption {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    color:white;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  }
  .captioned:hover .caption {
    display:block;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a span inside the anchor, give it an RGBA color of white with no alpha, then on hover change the alpha value, you'll get the effect you want with CSS alone:

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="darken">
    <img src="http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/example.jpg" width="200">
    <span>text</span>
</a>
```

Don't forget to position the span within the anchor, so that it doesn't display beneath the image.

```
a.darken {
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

a.darken span
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

a.darken:hover span
{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); 
}
```

​http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/4Dfpm/57/

Answer (score 0):

Check the fiddle :

> **http://jsfiddle.net/4Dfpm/59/**

all done throught css. althought you can achieve it with jQuery too,

your html i edited little bit:

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="darken">
    <img src="http://callzeb.com/themes/images/JQuery_logo.png">
    <span>123</span>
</a>
```

and edited little bit of css too:

```
a.darken {
   display: inline-block;
   background: black;
   padding: 0;
   width:229px;
   height:200px;
   overflow:hidden;
   position:relative;
   text-align:center;
}

a.darken img {
   display: block;

-webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
     -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
        transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

a.darken:hover img {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

a.darken:hover span{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    bottom:10px;
    color:red;
    font-size:24px;        
}

span{display:none;}
```